# how to write loop for a record type in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following statement which compiles fine in my package:

package header:

```
   TYPE role_user_type IS RECORD (
      ROLE_ID        some_table.ROLE_ID%TYPE,
      SUBGROUP       some_table.USER_ID%TYPE
   );
```

body:

```
ROLE_USER_REC                  MY_PACKAGE.ROLE_USER_TYPE;

SELECT B.USER_ID, B.ROLE INTO ROLE_USER_REC
FROM some_table where user_id like 'M%'
```

what is the skeleton for looping through `ROLE_USER_REC`? can we even loop through it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is nothing to loop.

`role_user_type` defines a single record, that you can access via:

```
dbms_output.put_line( role_user_rec.role_id || ', ' || role_user_rec.subgroup );
```

Your `SELECT ... INTO` will fail as soon as more than one row is returned.

---

If you need to store several of those records, you can use [nested tables](http://psoug.org/reference/nested_tab.html) like
`TYPE role_user_tab IS TABLE OF role_user_type`:

**Example**:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE role_user_type IS RECORD (
     ROLE_ID        VARCHAR2(10),
     SUBGROUP       VARCHAR2(10)
  );
  TYPE role_user_tab IS TABLE OF role_user_type;
  role_user_rec role_user_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'A', 'B'
  BULK COLLECT INTO role_user_rec
  FROM dual;
  FOR i IN role_user_rec.FIRST .. role_user_rec.LAST LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( role_user_rec(i).role_id || ', ' || role_user_rec(i).subgroup );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a cursor FOR loop:

```
BEGIN
  FOR role_user_type IN ('SELECT B.USER_ID, B.ROLE FROM some_table where user_id like ''M%'')
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('User ID: '||role_user_type.user_id);
    etc...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Another alternative:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR C IS
SELECT B.USER_ID, B.ROLE 
  FROM some_table 
 where user_id like 'M%';
BEGIN
  FOR role_user_type IN C LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('User ID: '||role_user_type.user_id);
    etc...
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use cursors for this

```
FOR i in (/* Your Select query*/)
loop
/* You can use value of the column fetched from select query like i.column_name
and use it which ever way you want */
end loop;
```